# Confused about a string hash function

Tags: string, algorithm, function, hash, substring

As I was looking through some string hash fucntions, I came across this one (code below). The function processes the string four bytes at a time, and interprets each of the four-byte chunks as a single long integer value. The integer values for the four-byte chunks are added together. In the end, the resulting sum is converted to the range 0 to M-1 using the modulus operator.
The following is the function code :

```
// Use folding on a string, summed 4 bytes at a time
long sfold(String s, int M) {
     int intLength = s.length() / 4;
     long sum = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) {
       char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
       long mult = 1;
       for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
     sum += c[k] * mult;
     mult *= 256;
       }
     }

     char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
     long mult = 1;
     for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
       sum += c[k] * mult;
       mult *= 256;
     }

     return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
   }
```

The confusion for me is this chunk of code, especially the first line.

```
     char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
     long mult = 1;
     for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
       sum += c[k] * mult;
       mult *= 256;
```

To my knowledge, the substring function used in this line takes as argument : *begin index* inclusive, The substring will start from the specified **beginIndex** and it will extend to the end of the string.
For the sake of example, let's assume we want to hash the following string : aaaabbbb. In this case **intLength** is going to be **2** (second line of function code). Replacing the value of intlength in `s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray()` will give us `s.substring(8).toCharArray()` which means string index is out of bounds given the string to be hashed has 8 characters.
I don't quite understand what's going on !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hash function is awful, but to answer your question:

There is no `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because `"aaaabbbb".substring(8)` is `""`

The purpose of that last loop is to deal with leftovers when the string length isn't a multiple of 4.  When `s` is `"aaaabbbbcc"`, for example, then `intLength == 2`, and `s.substring(8)` is `"cc"`.

Comment: Thank you, everthing is clear to me now.
Just one thing, would you care to explain what's awful about this function ?

Comment: Allocating new strings and new char arrays is relatively expensive and should be avoided in hash functions.  This function allocations length/4 of them for no good reason.